# Dragging image inside canvas to change its position

Tags: android, bitmap, drag-and-drop, android-canvas

I have a canvas that contains several bitmap images, I want the user to be able to move the images inside the canvas by touching any image and moving it.

Currently, my app has a canvas and an image view, whenever the canvas is updated, the image view will be updated also.

How could I do that, should I use SurfaceView or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Pre-honeycomb, or 3.0+? There was a lot of features for this added in API 11, its a bit more difficult for older devices.

Comment: @Tim Yes, pre-honeycomb, aren't these methods available in the support packages provided by Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement a custom View subclass which maintains a list of the images and their positions (and layer ordering), and displays them appropriately. Doing this is very easy: your subclass just has to start by overriding [View.onDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) to implement its custom drawing behaviour.

The next part is implementing [View.onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). Depending on the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) action, you will need to respond to ACTION_DOWN by finding out which image lies under the given coordinates, and ACTION_MOVE to change the position of that image accordingly. To trigger a display update, just call [View.invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) after changing the position of the image, and that will eventually flow through to your `onDraw` method.